# Android Parcelables

Tags: android, parcelable

I just have a quick questions. Code isnt really involved. When you have an android class that implements Parcelable, if there is an arrayList in the class, do you have to loop through the array list and individually write each element in the writeToParcel function?

Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can [use `writeList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeList%28java.util.List%29):

> Flatten a List into the parcel at the current dataPosition(), growing dataCapacity() if needed. The List values are written using [writeValue(Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29) and must follow the specification there.